# installing Ruby 1.9.1

Tags: ruby

I usually look to http://hivelogic.com for instructions on installing Ruby but I have run into problems trying to convert Dan's instructions for 1.8.7 to 1.9.1.

Comment: You need to describe your problems.

Comment: Maybe put a link to the exact page you're looking at on hivelogic.com

Comment: We can't do much without more specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's what I did](http://stuff.lilleaas.net/ruby_1.9_on_your_mac)! Summary:

- curl -O ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.1-p0.tar.gz
- tar xzvf ruby-1.9.1-p0.tar.gz
- cd ruby-1.9.1-p0
- ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --program-suffix=1.9
- make
- sudo make install